# how can i describe the processes status accurately(such as initialization,running,waiting etc) in c programming language?

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing

these status are based upon process status definition of linux operating system ,take waiting as a example ,when a  process is not reading from outside and not writing data to outside and  not computing inside, but difficulty is how can i know this process is not computing now, how to implement it  in c programming language?(if the process is not reading from outside,it can return a reading error that i know it is not reading now, so does writing).
eg:
Read(int fd, void *buf, size_t  const)
Write(int fd,void  *buf, size_t  const)

Comment: The answer is probably not language dependent, but it is platform dependent! Are you talking about an embedded device or something a PC?

Comment: Thanks, Bit Fiddling Code Monkey,i want the manager process control the worker process,and worker process describe the status to the shared memory so that the manager process can judge the worker process working well or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in a langauge independent way in C, because C has no notion of process.

However, in all reasonable circumstances in which your C program has access to a library that can launch threads/processes (e.g., Linux), it is typical for the process-launching call to return a ("process") "handle" (or some representative) of the process that was launched by the parent program.

The same library that has a procedure to launch a process, will invariably have a procedure to *inspect* the status of the launched process, using the process handle.

I'm not familiar with the libraries for Linux (and I suspect there are several). You must be using one if you've managed to launch a subprocess.  Go read about the other library elements until you find one that returns the process status.

Comment: Thanks，Ira,i think this might be depicted as a process checking problem. I want provide an example of how this is used in an application,this might help clarify the question,but i don't know how to upload my picture.

Comment: The question you asked was, "how to implement it in C..."  I gave the abstract answer; all you have do is fill in details.  What has "depicting" got to do with your original question?  You either found the process-inspection API, or you didn't.  Have you looked? *Where* did you look?

Comment: Thanks for your patient,i know that "waitpid" can provide this function.
I also posted this issue on quora because i don't konw how to upload my appliction model in stackoverflow.
The link is
http://www.quora.com/C-programming-language/How-can-i-describe-the-processes-status-accurately-such-as-initialization-running-waiting-etc-in-c-programming-language?__snids__=249753498&__nsrc__=1#comment417089